# Typo3 // news : Set Default value for excludeAlreadyDisplayedNews?

Tags: typo3, tsconfig

how do I set the default value für the field "excludeAlreadyDisplayedNews" in the news-Plugin for Typo3 (V9)

I tried

TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.tx_news.sDEF.settings.excludeAlreadyDisplayedNews=1

in the TSConfig, but this doesnt work....

Answer (score 0):

Just via TypoScript settings

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.excludeAlreadyDisplayedNews = 1
```